# objective-c Completion Block issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I am trying to get a `JSON (NSString *)` of the address book , in async task , however I want it to be asynchronously and with a completion block .

I have managed to retrieve that easy without the completion block , however when I am adding the completion block I have the following compiler error :

Incompatible block pointer types passing `NSString *(^)(bool, CFErrorRef)' to parameter of type 'ABAddressBookRequestAccessCompletionHandler' (aka 'void (^)(bool, CFErrorRef)')`

here is my code

```
+ (NSString *) getAddressBook:(id (^)())block {
ABAuthorizationStatus status = ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus();

if (status == kABAuthorizationStatusDenied)
{
    // if you got here, user had previously denied/revoked permission for your
    // app to access the contacts, and all you can do is handle this gracefully,
    // perhaps telling the user that they have to go to settings to grant access
    // to contacts
    [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:@"This app requires access to your contacts to function properly. Please visit to the \"Privacy\" section in the iPhone Settings app." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
    return nil;
}
CFErrorRef error = NULL;
ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, &error);

if (error)
{
    NSLog(@"ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions error: %@", CFBridgingRelease(error));
    if (addressBook) CFRelease(addressBook);
    return nil;
}

if (status == kABAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined)
{
    // present the user the UI that requests permission to contacts ...
    ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(addressBook, ^(bool granted, CFErrorRef error) -> THE ERROR OCCURS HERE !
                                             {...
```

I think the problem is within my completion blocks , but I can't find some good example/tutorial for my specific issue I would be really glad if some 1 could help me please.

Comment: The error is saying that the block you are passing in returns a NSString * while it expects the block to not return anything.

Comment: But I want to return NSString :-O how can I do so ?

Comment: You will need to do it else but cannot use ABAddressBookRequestAccessCompletionHandler for it.

Comment: Can you please point on possible solution please?

Comment: Where are you using this `block` you are passing as a parameter? Show us how are you calling this method

Comment: @Levi I have tried the answer and it worked , thanks anyways

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you are declaring getAddressBook like this(if we strip block)

```
-(id)block
```

And you are trying to pass it as a function of type:

```
-(void)block:(BOOL)aBool error:(CFErrorRef*)error
```

Blocks are quite hard to get used with syntax(which is improved in swift) however I'm always refering to this site when not sure:

[block syntax reference](http://fuckingblocksyntax.com/)

UPDATE:

You have to actually wait for your async method finish. You may also refer to [official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithBlocks/WorkingwithBlocks.html)

```
+ (void) getAddressBook:((^)(NSString* result))block {
    ABAuthorizationStatus status = ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus();

    if (status == kABAuthorizationStatusDenied)
    {
        // if you got here, user had previously denied/revoked permission for your
        // app to access the contacts, and all you can do is handle this gracefully,
        // perhaps telling the user that they have to go to settings to grant access
        // to contacts
        [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:@"This app requires access to your contacts to function properly. Please visit to the \"Privacy\" section in the iPhone Settings app." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
        block(nil);
    }
    CFErrorRef error = NULL;
    ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, &error);

    if (error)
    {
        NSLog(@"ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions error: %@", CFBridgingRelease(error));
        if (addressBook) CFRelease(addressBook);
        block(nil);
    }

    if (status == kABAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined)
    {


        // present the user the UI that requests permission to contacts ...
        ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(addressBook, ^(bool granted, CFErrorRef error) -> THE ERROR OCCURS HERE !
                                                 {
                                                     NSString* result = whatever

                                                     block(result);
                                                 });
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
[YourClass getAddressBook:^(NSString* result)
 {
     //now you really have result
 }];
```

Comment: I will try it asap :)

Comment: I have posted some code as edit, you may find it useful.

Comment: I am already done it , however i have a question : Do i still need a block ? in side my method declaration >?

Comment: I removed the block from the method declaration and now it is fine Thanks :)

Comment: You're welcome. You could check my edited answer. You may also call block(@"blabla") in other cases with relative string whenever you feel appropriate.

Comment: on your updated answer i have an error on the block declaration "expected a type"

Comment: Also it has an error  use of undeclared indetifier result